# Css-responsive navbar only drop down (in mobile size) for the homepage, not others (html code is identical)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-website

I have a bit of a confusing issue. I'm building a website with bootstrap, and I have a bootstrap navbar that (when the page is shrunk down to mobile) shrinks the menu down to one box that drops down the menu options when you click it. The issue is that the navbar menu drops down only on the home page.  I copy-pasted the html code for the navbar for the other pages, but still the mobile drop-down only works on the main page. Any thoughts on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your vendor Javascript and Bootstrap Javascript linked on the other pages as well? It sounds like you have linked the Javascript files on your homepage but forgot to add it to the other pages.

It would help a lot to see your code.

Comment: That was it! I had linked some of the files (the CSS and JS ones at the top of the page) but not two at the bottom of the page! Thanks for the thought!